# How do I access the UserManager from a Code-first Migration?

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to use my `ApplicationUserManager` to seed a new user during a database migration. I attempted to create a constructor and add the `ApplicationUserManager` as a parameter, in hopes that dependency injection would apply.

Instead I simply get "No parameterless constructor defined for type 'migrationName'." I can certainly add a parameterless constructor, but that would defeat the whole point. *IS* there any way to get a user manager instance while applying the migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly, you can't access any entity model or db context related class inside the migration class code.

It's because the migration class just describes the model transformation, rather than executing it. For instance, it's also used by the EF Core tools for finding model differences which then are used to generate new migration.

Also the entity model (CLR classes/properties) can be very different from what they were when the migration was created - your code always contains the latest, so they need to store the model information is some alternative way not using the regular classes. To do that they use EF Core metadata and builder APIs with string overloads to describe the old and new models at the migration time.

So, all you can do inside the migration is to use the available primitives or raw SQL (which also will be executed only when the migration is applied).

And in general the database migrations should not be sensitive to who is executing them. Except if you are trying to implement multi tenant multi database scenario, but that would require different approach and is not handled well (if at all) with the current EF Core migration system.

Depending of the actual problem, there are some complicated workarounds with special placeholders (or annotations) in EF Core metadata and custom SQL generator or other service replacing the EF Core ones, but they should be used with care because they rely on EF Core internals, which change very often, thus need to be kept in sync.

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes total sense. I hadn't thought about the fact that the UserManager and the Entity models could be very different from when the Migration was written. Bummer. Oh well. I was hoping to avoid putting this in Startup, but I guess there's no getting around it. Thanks.